# Performing Random Under-sampling after SMOTE using imblearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, imblearn, smote

I am trying to implement combining over-sampling and under-sampling using `RandomUnderSampler()` and `SMOTE()`.

I am working on the loan_status dataset.

I have done the following split.

```
X = df.drop(['Loan_Status'],axis=1).values   # independant features
y = df['Loan_Status'].values# dependant variable
```

This is how my training data's distribution looks like.

[image: target variable frequency count]

this is the code snippet that i tried to execute for class-balancing.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.1)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
pipeline = make_pipeline(over,under)
    
x_sm,y_sm = pipeline.fit_resample(X_train,y_train)
```

it gave me a ValueError with the following traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_64588/3438707951.py in <module>
      4 pipeline = make_pipeline(over,under)
      5 
----> 6 x_copy,y_copy = pipeline.fit_resample(x_train_copy,y_train_copy)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py in fit_resample(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    351             fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
    352             if hasattr(last_step, "fit_resample"):
--> 353                 return last_step.fit_resample(Xt, yt, **fit_params_last_step)
    354 
    355     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate="_final_estimator")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in fit_resample(self, X, y)
     77         X, y, binarize_y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
     78 
---> 79         self.sampling_strategy_ = check_sampling_strategy(
     80             self.sampling_strategy, y, self._sampling_type
     81         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in check_sampling_strategy(sampling_strategy, y, sampling_type, **kwargs)
    532         return OrderedDict(
    533             sorted(
--> 534                 _sampling_strategy_float(sampling_strategy, y, sampling_type).items()
    535             )
    536         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in _sampling_strategy_float(sampling_strategy, y, sampling_type)
    391             ]
    392         ):
--> 393             raise ValueError(
    394                 "The specified ratio required to generate new "
    395                 "sample in the majority class while trying to "

ValueError: The specified ratio required to generate new sample in the majority class while trying to remove samples. Please increase the ratio.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the sampling strategy for the `SMOTE` because `((y_train==0).sum())/((y_train==1).sum())` is higher than `0.1`. It seems that your starting imbalance ratio is about (by eye) `0.4`. Try:

```
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.5)
```

Finally you probably want an equal final ratio (after the under-sampling) so you should set the sampling strategy to `1.0` for the `RandomUnderSampler`:

```
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=1)
```

Try this way and if you have other problems give me a feedback.

Comment: Thanks! i will try this out and let you know if it works :D